# Rails 3 change path to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am passing a path as a parameter, so `params[:path]` would be `name_path(:username => @user.name` (I want to pass it as a path and not a url, so putting name_url in the params isn't what I want).

Since you can only use `redirect_to` with a url, I need to change the path to a url before I can use redirect_to. How would I do this?

I found this method [here](http://grosser.it/2008/11/24/rails-transform-path-to-url/)

```
def path_to_url(path)
  "http://#{request.host_with_port_without_standard_port_handling}/#{path.sub(%r[^/],'')}"
end
```

But, this was written in 2008, and I want to know if there is a better way in Rails 3?

Comment: I said I want to avoid that approach in my question. If my url changes, then the old url will still be in the database unless I use _path.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but sometimes when you are fighting against the language so much there may be a bigger picture problem. Are you sure that achieving this is a good idea, and there isn't another simpler approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated copy from original [path to url post](http://grosser.it/2008/11/24/rails-transform-path-to-url/) btw: also works on Rails 2

```
# abs or /abs -> http://myx.com/abs
# http://grosser.it/2008/11/24/rails-transform-path-to-url
def path_to_url(path)
  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port.sub(/:80$/,"")}/#{path.sub(/^\//,"")}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `redirect_to` with a path as long as its a route defined in the routes file for the current application. Thats seems to be the case from your question.

ie, `name_path(:username => @user.name)`

So the following should be valid.

redirect_to params[:path]

Comment: The HTTP spec requires a fully qualified URL when doing 302 Redirect and friends, and it will work in some lenient browsers, but _path should not be used. (from Agile Web Development with Rails)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
def path_to_url(path)
  "http://#{request.host}/#{path.sub(%r[^/],'')}"
end
```